# service or activity starting with application context vs activity context

Tags: android

We need a context to call start a service or activity in android. What difference does it make when I start a service or activity using

- an application context
- or an activity context

If it does make difference can someone give an example as to when to use application context to start them and when to use activity context to start them

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

> What difference does it make when I start a service or activity using an application context or an activity context

There is no difference for `startActivity()`. `startActivityForResult()`, though, is not available on `Application`.

Generally, you only use `Application` when you know exactly why you are using `Application`.